# Is this question actually a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, dupehammer

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554977/how-to-centre-navbar-logo-in-boostrap-4-with-nav-links-below) question in the Reopen Votes Review Queue and noticed it had been marked as a duplicate. I then looked through the duplicate and, from what I could tell, none of the answers actually provide an answer for the OP's requirement.

As the comment from @Anuresh suggests (and confirmed by the OP), the OP is looking for a way to acomplish this:

[image]

(Notice the 'logo' image and links being on a separate 'rows')

I also noticed that two other users had also voted to keep it closed.

Am I missing something or is this actually not a duplicate?

Comment: I closed it as dup because, while it wouldn't appear to be an *exact* dup, the answer is the same: "use flexbox and auto margins" which is exactly how the Navbar alignment and positioning is done in all the other [tag:bootstrap-4] related answers. I don't think there is any benefit to re-hashing each specific navbar center scenario. The OP also didn't appear to make any effort to center or separate rows on their own.

Comment: @ZimSystem fair enough, I was just curious to the thinking behind it as I didn't understand. Appreciate the clarification.